# Find a string with newline or whitespace to fix broken xml input

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Hello I have trouble finding a string within a file which consists of the following signs and a whitespace or a newline.
I want to find the broken tag

```
</answ
```

to replace it later... the xml file lokks like the following:

"

[image]

Normally i thought i could find this by

```
search = i.find('</answ ') 

#or newline by:
vorkommen = i.find('</answ \n ')
```

But it returns both -1...and thats not true...

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Is i a single line from the file?

Comment: `\\n` is not a newline. `\n` is. Also, please show the value of `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could broaden your set of whitespace characters to include tabs as follows.

```
import re
search = re.search(r'</answ\s', i).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use an xml parser to locate the errors?

`etree.fromstring(u'<foo>text</fo\no>')` raises `XMLSyntaxError: expected '>', line 2, column 1`, so as long as you're keeping your text in some kind of stream, you can manipulate it to remove the newline, and re-parse.

The exception raised sets the `position` property, as well as the code property.

Alternatively, you can configure lxml to try to be more robust:

```
In [39]: parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)

In [40]: etree.fromstring(u'<foo>text</fo\no>', parser)
Out[40]: <Element foo at 0x55fd798>
```

See: http://lxml.de/parsing.html and also, the API reference at http://lxml.de/api/index.html and http://lxml.de/api.html#error-handling-on-exceptions

Comment: @Jurudocs: I have added a bunch of information on error handling with lxml

Comment: that sounds great. Especially the "make lxml try to be more robust" Thanks a lot..good additional helpful information...